# Performance of DOSBox on PS Vita

Tags: ps-vita, psp, dosbox

For owners (previous or current) of PSP that now have a Ps Vita: how is the performance of DOSBox compared to the performance on a PSP?

I'm asking this because I already own a PSP and tons of games and emus, but the performance of DOSBox on PSP is so bad. I want to upgrade my PSP and my budget could afford a PS Vita (maaaaybe a Switch), but if the performance is minimal then I see no point on buying one...

Comment: If all you want to do is play DOSBox (which I assume requires a jailbroken Vita), then I'd recommend getting a Switch instead. With the Vita in end-of-life, you might have trouble fixing your Vita if anything happens (dead/bloated battery, dead/cracked screen, etc.). Also, Vita memory cards are proprietary and extremely expensive, though you probably won't need much for DOSBox.

Comment: @Nolonar Yeah, it will require jailbroke but, what Vita is not jailbroken today?. Spare parts are not my concern, that's what Aliexpress and Amazon Marketplace are for. Memory is not a concern neither, a simple Vita2SD adapter will work fine. What I need to know is how is Vita's performance whrn running old DOS games through DOSBox. I tried to run Twinsen's Oddesy once and it run like shit...